# Laptop RCA Connectivity

Tags: external-hard-drive

Is it possible to connect a CD/DVD Burner to a laptop computer with an RCA to 3.5mm auxiliary jack to watch movies? I have tried to connect this cable that I bought with the laptop computer to Flat screen television sets, but I found it to be incompatible. I am thinking of buying a CD burner, and have found there might be a problem with picture quality.

Comment: I have an external USB burner/player.  It works perfectly even though this isn't a common format anymore.   I wouldn't try using RCA for my connector.  You will be lucky to get it to work.

Comment: RCA composite video is well known to have artifacts due to the way video signals are blended together. It is an ancient system, is low resolution and should not be used anywhere you care about quality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video#Composite_artifacts

Comment: Quite unexpected question in 2023 and by someone from Syracuse, NY (!!!) It would be "weird" still if it was asked by someone in a poor 3rd world country but less so.

Comment: There's got to be a good reason for it :D

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to connect a CD/DVD Burner to a laptop computer with an RCA to 3.5mm auxiliary jack to watch movies?

**No, it isn't.**

The typical AV outputs of a standalone DVD player with the "RCA" connectors are a composite video (yellow) plus L+R audio (white/red). The ONLY way to use such a device with a PC is by having a video capture card with the corresponding inputs. And, of course, given this scenario, the player can be anything that outputs the same signal.

The year being 2023, it is quite fascinating to see such "archaic" questions about obsolete technologies here. DVD is limited to SD (standard definition, 480P (PAL/SECAM) or 576P (NTSC)). We have 8K now, enough said.

The cable you have, supposedly a 3.5mm jack in one end and the 3 aforementioned "RCA" connectors is for use ONLY with compatible devices, the ones with a 3.5mm AV output which is arguably weird but works and saves a lot of space in the device. **There's no such thing in a PC!**

As commented under the question, use any external USB burner/player (DVD at least, or Blu-Ray) and proper media player software (e.g. VLC).